# Why was www ever prefixed to websites / Purpose of www prefix

Tags: http, url

So a full URL for a website would be
http://www.google.com:80
or https://www.google.com:443 (because everyone should use SSL).

The http bit, the www bit and the :80 bit all say essentially the same thing.  Traffic over 80 is normally http traffic, and www seems redundant as well.

So, why does a URL have so many redundant elements?  Or, what have I misunderstood.

Comment: They're not redundant and don't say the same thing. Port 80 can be used for anything. HTTP can go through any port. Host name beginning with www can have anything and not a web server at all.

Comment: Relevant link: http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/

Comment: Have you ever seen urls like images.google.com?

Comment: @takendarkk Yes, I have been on the internet before.  I was after why www was ever there at all?  Anyway, I now have an answer.

Comment: Not really a programming question...

Answer (score 8):

Because, hard as it may to believe, the web is a new thing, and the internet existed LONG before the "world wide web" ever existed. It's only a "recent" thing that you can assume that ANY domain name is also usable as a web address. It used to be the case that `example.com` would be something completely DIFFERENT than a webserver, so you explicitly marked a server as your webserver, and called it `www.example.com`.

And urls are generalized as well. http by default is port 80, but it can also be on any **OTHER** port, so

```
http://example.com:80
http://example.com
```

**MAY** be equivalent and point at the exact same resource, but that doesn't mean it **HAS** to be port 80. Maybe someone's actually running their website on

```
http://example.com:8080
```

and port 80 is used for something completely different.

Comment: Pedantically, those two URLs you listed **MUST** be equivalent per RFC-3986 because `80` is the defined default port for the `http` scheme.

Comment: So in essence, you're saying (if I have understood correctly), that www stands for _website_, ie something a user can browse. So valid websites would be abcp://www.example.com:80 or defp://www.example.com:123, there all _websites_ just using non-standard protocols and ports?

Comment: @user3157094 A "website" as we think of it must generally use the HTTP or HTTPS protocol. (You can get similar behaviour through some other protocols, but that's really stretching the definition of "website".) A website may be served on any port -- URL schemes may have default ports, but it's usually possible to use alternatives. My impression of Marc's key point is that, back when the web was new, institutions like universities already had non-web servers operating at `example.edu` -- perhaps a big centralized Unix server that everybody logged in to to do their work. When they decided...

Comment: ... they wanted to get a website, they might purchase a new web server (partially because just running one on their existing hardware may have been more challenging with their resources at the time). This server couldn't have the same address as the old one, so the convention developed of using the `www.` prefix to identify the web server associated with an institution's hostname. It would have been possible for some institutions to choose a different prefix (like `web.`), but that would have been more confusing for users. There are other reasons to use subdomains but I think this is primary.

Comment: @jeremy_banks Thanks, that's actually really helpful! And a bit of history I was missing / struggling to find!

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, on the internet there are websites, protocols and ports.  They don't all mean the same thing and while standards have evolved, the system is as open as possible to allow competition of standards.

A website is a conceptual thing, it is something you can browse.

A protocol is a method of transferring files, like ftp, https, http etc

A port is a way of speaking to a specific process at the other computer.

Websites are normally delivered using http or https on ports 80 and 443.  That doesn't mean they have to be.  Imagine that instead of http we lived in a world of two competing protocols for viewing websites: betamax (bmp) and vhs (vhsp).  Your website www.example.com, could be served on both bmp and vhsp, e.g.

bmp://www.example.com
vhsp://www.example.com

For maximum viewability.

As a standard, bmp could be served on port 1 and vhsp could be served on port 2.  But there may be an instance where port 2 was occupied by something else.  In this case you would tell users to use the non-standard port 3 instead

vhsp://www.example.com:3

Of course, a protocol can be served on any port, and www doesn't necessarily mean that it is a website, that is just a standard that has evolved.  We generally drop the port number as port 80 is the standard for http.  We also normally drop the http bit as it is assumed these days since most internet traffic is http.

Finnaly, a note on subdomains.  If you own exmaple.com, you might want to generate additional websites (e.g. a mobile site).  You can use subdomains to do this and exchange www for m on the mobile site.  There are groups for and against using www but most big websites use www for a variety of reasons.

In summary, they aren't redundant, you have confused websites and http as being the same thing.